# Cards(hero,sign,receipt and thumpnail) , button and image are not appearing on skype bot

Tags: bots

I have created sample Skype bot and deployed on the portal using the following card in which I attached few images and buttons. when I tested the application in Emulator these card is displaying with button and image.

[image]

Hero Card
Thumbnail Card
Receipt Card
Sign-In Card

After deployed the application on the portal, the image and button are not appearing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I updated my Skype version and that fixed the problem for me.